# Creating a NodeJS module with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I'm trying to write a Node module with TypeScript, this is how far I got:

**MysqlMapper.ts**

```
export class MysqlMapper{

    private _config: Mysql.IConnectionConfig;

    private openConnection(): Mysql.IConnection{
        ...
    }

    private createSelectAllQuery(constructor): string{
    ...
    }

    public getAll<T>(constructor): Q.Promise<Array<T>>{
    .....
    }
    constructor(config: Mysql.IConnectionConfig){
    ... 
    }

}
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from "./MysqlMapper";
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mysql-metadata-orm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Simple ORM using reflect-metadata",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "author": "+",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.9.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2"
  }
}
```

I activated the declaration-generation in my tsconfig-file, but I really don't understand how to get a declaration file which allows to import the module like this:

```
import * as Mapper from "mysql-metadata-mapper"
```

I hope someone can help me with this, because it drives me very crazy.

**@Update**

These are the generated .d.ts-Files:

**index.d.ts**

```
export * from "./MysqlMapper";
```

**MysqlMapper.d.ts**

```
import * as Q from "q";
import * as Mysql from "mysql";
export declare class MysqlMapper {
    private _config;
    private openConnection();
    private createSelectAllQuery(constructor);
    getAll<T>(constructor: any): Q.Promise<Array<T>>;
    constructor(config: Mysql.IConnectionConfig);
}
```

**How do I get the declaration file?**

Comment: Can you maybe post here what the auto generated declarations produce for this module?

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but for anyone else stumbling across it later (as I did this past week), you might find this typescript boilerplate project helpful: https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you make your own declaration file: (e.g. `globals.d.ts`)

```
declare module 'mysql-metadata-mapper' {
    import * as mapper from './MysqlMapper';
    export = mapper;
}
```

then you can reference this declaration file e.g.
`/// <reference path="../globals.d.ts" />`

and import the module as you like with:

`import * as Mapper from 'mysql-metadata-mapper'`

I'm not 100% sure if this is the cleanest solution, but at least it should work like you want it.

Comment: First thank you for your answer, but you suggestion has some problems, first the - in metadata-mapper is not allowed, no problem I changed the name.
But now i get a error at the import statement:
Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.

Comment: I see - I didn't test it with the dashes in name. Did you try to import without './' ?

Comment: Yes I did, but the module isnt found this way

Comment: After some research, it seems that it cannot work this way by declaring ambient module. There must be another way - but I also have no suggestion right now. I will come back to this answer asap.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your bother, i allready inspected the definition files of other node module but i don't get behind the system :/

Comment: I started to bug me also - apparently myy solution seems to have worked at some point. Maybe this can post help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739044/how-do-you-write-a-node-module-using-typescript