# Typescript migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

The question is how to write a nodejs (commonJS) module in Typescript?
I have a node.js module  like this :

```
var testController = require("/controllers/test").
app.get('/testTS', testController.getUsers);
```

In test.js file, I have

```
exports.getUsers = function(req,res) {}.
```

If I have to convert my test.js file to Typescript, how would I proceed? 
I am compiling with commonjs module. Here is the file I tried :

```
 module user {
     export class getUsers {
          constructor(req:any, res:any) {}
     }
    }
    module.exports = user;
```

If I convert this file to JS, there are no callbacks of type

```
exports.getUsers = function(req,res);
```

If I say like

```
 var testController = require("/controllers/test").
testController.getUsers() => this works. but I cannot specify this in 
app.get('testTS', testController.getUsers());
```

Can someone help me to write the callbacks like this in Typescript?

Comment: Well for one, you are mixing getUser and getUsers. I don't think that's your issue though. Can you use https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ to type out what you are inputting as I'm lost on if the last . is there on purpose or what?

Comment: Here's something that might help: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20namespace%20app%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20users%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor()%7B%0D%0A%09%09%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%09%20%20%0D%0A%09%09%20%20getUsers(req%3A%20any%2C%20res%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%20%20%0D%0A%09%09%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0Alet%20exports%20%3D%20new%20app.users()%3B%0D%0Aexports.getUsers(1%2C%202)%3B

Comment: The question is how to write a nodejs (commonJS) module in Typescript?

Comment: You mean like http://stackoverflow.com/q/23739044/215552?