# How to create node.js module using Typescript

Tags: node.js, node-modules, typescript1.8

The very simple module that I've created to test the viability of this endeavor. Here is the beginning of `SPServerApp.ts`:

```
class SPServerApp {
    public AllUsersDict: any;
    public AllRoomsDict: any;
    constructor () {
        this.AllUsersDict = {};
        this.AllRoomsDict = {};
    }
}
module.exports = SPServerApp();
```

Then in my app, I have this require statement:

```
var serverapp = require('./SPServerApp');
```

I then try to access one of the dictionaries like so:

```
serverapp.AllUsersDict.hasOwnProperty(nickname)
```

But get the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks, E.

Comment: You aren't instantiating the class. Add 'new' or create a new instance where you're requiring it.

Comment: That worked indeed. Thank you Phix.

Comment: I think this link will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739044/how-do-you-write-a-node-module-using-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot the 'new' keyword when calling the constructor. The line should read:

```
module.exports = new SPServerApp();
```

If you don't use *new* your constructor will be treated as a normal function and will just return undefined (since you did not return anything explicitly). Also 'this' will not point to what you expect within the constructor.

Omitting *new* in Node is actually quite common. But for this to work you have to explicitly guard against *new*-less calls in the constructor like so:

```
constructor () {
    if (! (this instanceof SPServerApp)) {
        return new SPServerApp();
    }
    this.AllUsersDict = {};
    this.AllRoomsDict = {};
}
```

BTW, in TypeScript you can also use module syntax. The TS compiler will translate this into the export/require statements. With ES6 style modules your example would look like this:

```
export class SPServerApp {
    public AllUsersDict: any;
    public AllRoomsDict: any;
    constructor () {
        this.AllUsersDict = {};
        this.AllRoomsDict = {};
    }
}
export var serverapp = new SPServerApp();
```

In your other TS file you just import:

```
import { serverapp } from './SPServerApp';

serverapp.AllUsersDict.hasOwnProperty('something');
```